# C++ program speeds up when re-executed

Tags: c++, performance, ubuntu, memory-management, clion

I am currently doing a performance testing of a C++ program. I need to bulk insert to a `std::unordered_map` or some other similar open source structure. I am inserting 30-40 char strings as key-value pairs and noticed an interesting behaviour. When code is first executed (**Clion**), it took 20 seconds to complete, I repeated the test (changing nothing), it was 14s, then again 8s, 4s, the code now runs around 3s. I should repeat, the only expensive operation in my code is bulk unordered_map **insert**, multithreaded with `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`.

Another information that is important is that I am reading these keys and values from files. So I thought about some file caching happening in **Ubuntu**. But I was doing the same thing with different mechanisms and never experienced such a thing. Then I thought about some RAM allocation trick that may be keeping most of the map intact after the program is ended. But I am doing nothing to make that happen.

Why is this happening ? More than that, how can I reset this ? I need to do objective tests because my code will run in multiple servers without any pre-caching what so ever.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first time you run the code it has to:

- Wake up the disk if it's spun down or idle
- Read the data off disk
- Read the executable off disk
- Possibly load in some shared libraries as well

The second time you run the code it can:

- Read the data from the OS read-cache in memory
- Read the executable from the OS read-cache in memory
- Read the shared libraries from the OS read-cache in memory
- Throttle up the CPU to a higher frequency now that it's under load

This is why it's important to run tests *multiple times* and for an *extended period of time*, not just seconds but at least 10-15 minutes continuously.

Your execution times will vary dramatically at first, but will converge to more consistent values later. You can always sort by run-time and find the 95th percentile, that is the time the program runs in 95% of the time.

Comment: and be aware that all that measurement can go out the window once the program is deployed on another hardware/environment.

Comment: @bolov Absolutely. All bets are off when you move to a different piece of hardware. You can only get a general sense with one data point (one machine).

Comment: all true, but this cannot explain gradually decreasing from 20 to 3 seconds, or can it?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Sure can if your CPU was in a low-power state, then woke up to "turbo". I've seen this on some laptops where the resting CPU is ~1GHz and the turbo is ~4GHz. Spinny disk plus sleepy CPU means wildly divergent times. For I/O limited tasks the divergence can be even wider, like MB/s for a disk vs. GB/s for memory.

Comment: @idclev463035818 if data are loaded from a slow hard drive the first run (maybe randomly) and then for the next run data are loaded from memory, the performance difference can be 1 or 2 orders of magnitude. Actually, data may even be loaded directly from the CPU caches and so even faster faster (due to the throughput and the lower latency)!

Comment: @JérômeRichard Good point about CPU cache. Some modern CPUs have some absolutely ridiculous amounts of L2/L3 cache!

Comment: @JérômeRichard Need to say all data is on SSD, of course it is nowhere near a cache, but an information anyway.

Comment: @MaxPaython Your SSD may be quite fast but it's not going to be as fast as L2 or L3 CPU cache. Even as new technologies emerge that make your disk faster, your CPU more efficient or whatever, these rules will still apply. You need a lot of samples to get an accurate result.